# What is your favorite group?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, big-list

I would like to know about your favorite group(s). Since groups do appear everywhere in mathematics and there are plenty of them, which ones have drawn your attention the most or surprised you? Please not just name the group, but also provide some facts about it why you find this one particularly interesting.

I'll start by mentioning [Grigorchuks group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group). 
Because is was the first group i encountered, wich is finitely generated but not finitely presented. Also it was the first group discovered with intermediate growth. It has a lot of "strange" properties like:

- it's infinite but residually finite
- it's amenable but not elementary amenable
- every proper quotient group is finite
- every maximal subgroup has finite index

Also Grigorchuks group acts as a key-counterexample in infinite group theory. My professor once told me: "If you have a conjecture about infinite groups, try it one Grigorchuks group. If it holds, it might be worth trying to prove it."

edit: flagged for community wiki.

Comment: The monster group. Its a true monstrosity.

Comment: I think this is a nice question, or rather the answers could be nice.

Comment: For much more trivial reasons "my group" is the $PSL(2,7)\cong GL(3,2)$, aka. the smallest simple group if one doesn't count cyclic and alternating groups. This guy crept up everywhere in my first university semester ...

Comment: would it be more appropriate to ask for examples of groups with "strange" (in the sense of counter-intuitive) properties? like grigorchuks group. i think Dietrich Burdes awnser would also count for that, since it's a really small group wich inherits alot of structual implications. i'd really like to know wich groups are interesting to others and why.

Comment: I want to know how  Grigorchuks group was the first group you came across?

Comment: @hmmmm it wasn't the first group i came across. it was the first group i came across, that had some really strange behavior and so it stuck in my brain :D

Comment: Ah sorry I misread, I see that you said it was the first group you came across that was finitely gend but not presented!

Answer (score 1):

What about the smallest non-trivial group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ? See the discussion [Fantastic properties of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148925/fantastic-properties-of-z-2z) for many convincing arguments.